# pymongo insert all data in string format

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, csv, pymongo

I am importing csv using pymongo then inserting it into mongodb but due to some reason all field is in format of string where i was expecting double. Below is python code .

```
def saveToMongo():
print("inside saveToMongo")
collection = mydb['country']

header = ['country_id','country_name','zone_id','minLat','maxLat','minLong','maxLong']
csvFile = open('country.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)

print(reader)

for each in reader:
    row = {}
    for field in header:
        row[field] = each[field]

    #print(row)
    collection.insert(row)
```

and here is the csv file

```
country_id,country_name,zone_id,minLat,maxLat,minLong,maxLong
2,Bangladesh,1,20.6708832870000,26.4465255803000,88.0844222351000,92.6727209818000
3,"Sri Lanka",1,5.9683698592300,9.8240776636100,79.6951668639000,81.7879590189000
4,Pakistan,1,23.6919650335000,37.1330309108000,60.8742484882000,77.8374507995000
5,Bhutan,1,26.7194029811000,28.2964385035000,88.8142484883000,92.1037117859000
```

I am unable to understand why python is storing data in String format.

When i try to insert data using mongoimport I'm getting belopw error

```
fatal error: unrecognized DWARF version in .debug_info at 6

runtime stack:
panic during panic

runtime stack:
stack trace unavailable
```

Comment: What about using [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/)? There you can define the data types (using option `--columnsHaveTypes`) and most likely it will be much faster than Python.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i have tried with mongoImport but still i'm getting issue ..please check I have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv.DictReader just parse any data as String.

If you want another format you can create custom function to parse them in the type you want.

Considering that what you call `double` is a `float` in python, you could do something as follow :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
import csv
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydbname"]

def csvToMongo():
  with open('country.csv','r') as myFile :
    reader = csv.DictReader(myFile, delimiter=",")
    myParsedData = [
      {
        'country_id' : int(elem['country_id']),
        'country_name' : elem['country_name'],
        'zone_id' : int(elem['zone_id']),
        'minLat' : float(elem['minLat']),
        'maxLat' : float(elem['maxLat']),
        'minLong' : float(elem['minLong']),
        'maxLong' : float(elem['maxLong']),
      }
      for elem in reader
    ]
    collection = mydb['country']
    collection.insert_many(myParsedData)

#execute function
csvToMongo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python will read all CSV data in string format. This has nothing to do with MongoDB or *pymongo inserting data in string format*.

If you want type inference & automatic conversion from your CSV data, use something like [Pandas `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Otherwise, **do the type conversion** in a similar loop with `header` - create a mapping between the field names and field types, then convert each field to that type:

```py
header = {
    'country_id': int, 'country_name': str, 'zone_id': int,
    'minLat': float, 'maxLat': float, 'minLong': float, 'maxLong': float
}

for row in reader:
    doc = {}
    for field, ftype in header.items():
        doc[field] = ftype(row[field])
    
    # the `doc=` + loop lines can also be written in one line as:
    # doc = {field: ftype(row[field]) for field, ftype in header.items()}

    collection.insert(row)
```

*(Without that, the loop to read the data per row and assign to each key in a dict is quite redundant. Could be just `collection.insert(each)`)*

Btw, if your file isn't big, read & convert all the rows and then use `insert_many`.